# Ignore/handle 'unexpected indent' error. Get indent stack level

Tags: python, exception, indentation

I want to use indentations for code control, and have two questions.

1) Is it possible to force python ignore 'unexpected indent' errors?
Code like this raises 'unexpected indent' exception.

```
def test():
    print ('hello')
        print ('again!')
```

Is here any flag or another trick to execute above code as normal?

2) How I can get indention level in my program? Is something like that possible:

```
import introspectionmagic
def a():
    l = introspectionmagic.get_indent_level_of_function_call ()
    print ('level =', l)
def test():
    a()
        a()
```

Output:

```
level = 1
level = 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: 99% sure the answer is "1) No. 2) No." but I can't back it up with any sources.

Answer (score 0):

IndentationErrors are syntax errors; they happen at compile time, not run time. So you can't do anything in code to ignore them; you'd need to change the parser somehow.

You might consider using Python's context managers. These enable running specific code when entering a block; this might fit your use case, even if the actual enter code is pretty trivial. See the [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) module for some examples.